# CSS is not loading when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

my webpage is not loading when page is refreshed but second time it is loading css and after another     page refresh is not loading css and so on.
 would any budy will help me for this issue because i am working on this issue from last two days.

Comment: clear your browser cache. test on different browsers. check in chrome incognito mode.

Comment: just do a hard reload on your browser

Comment: this is not working? can you giveme some other solutions??

Comment: this is the same thing like some time facebook page does not load css on slow connection. and when i am disabling browser cache this is working absolutly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you can load css file via javascript, try this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?randomNum">
```

where randomNum is a dynamically generated number or whatever (as long as it's different everytime)